# Redux normalized tree in ngFor presentation

Tags: angular, functional-programming, redux, flux, ngrx

I am at the app design stage. It will be Angular4 application with using Redux. I read a lot about state tree normalization, and I have a little doubt about presentation data from state in view.

**From the beginning:**

I have to present for user expendable list of groups. For groups I have to call API. API returns me array of groups, f.e.:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "type": "GROUP"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "type": "GROUP"
  },
  ...
]
```

I know, that I should store this data in state tree in this way:

```
groups: {
  byId: {
    1: {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "type": "GROUP"
    },
    2: {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "type": "GROUP"
    }
  },
  allIds: [1, 2]
}
```

I guess that if I want to present this data in ***ngFor** loop, it will be looks like that:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let groupId of (groups | async).allIds"> {{ (groups | async).byId[groupId].name }} </li>
</ul>
```

and it's fine for me (I hope that I understand it well).

**Second step:**

But every group has a child list. Due to the large amount of data, childs for some group will be load from API after click the group.

so after two clicks in both groups state tree may looks like that:

```
  groups: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "GROUP",
        "childs": [ 1, 3, 4 ]
      },
      2: {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "name2",
        "type": "GROUP",
        "childs": [ 2, 5 ]
      }
    },
    "allIds": [ 1, 2 ]
  },
  childs: {
    byId: {
      1: {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "item1",
        "type": "CHILD"
      },
      2: {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "item2",
        "type": "CHILD"
      },
      3: {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "item3",
        "type": "CHILD"
      },
      4: {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "item4",
        "type": "CHILD"
      },
      5: {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "item5",
        "type": "CHILD"
      }
    },
    "allIds": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  }
```

And my **question**:
How I can present this data?

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let groupId of (groups | async).allIds">
    {{ (groups | async).byId[groupId].name }}
    <div *ngFor="let childId of (groups | async).byId[groupId].childs"> {{ (childs | async).byId[childId].name }} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is my way of thinking good? If changing child element (name f.e) in state, html view will be changing automatically? The same question applies to group changes.  I wish to avoid defeat, after a long implementation. Is normalization here needed at all?